# Comparing the record count between source and target database

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have a couple of tables and i load the source data in to target from a text file.
It loaded successfully.

Now I want to a report to see how many records are loaded into the target files.
I am loading the data using the shell script.

My requirement is calculate the records count for source and target it has to send into separate text file.

Example:I have 3 tables emp1, emp2,emp3 as a source oracle database. I load the date into 3 different text files using shell script. I want to know the source record count and target record count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sql returns with the row count for a table:

```
select count(*) from table
```

And the `wc` shell command returns with the line count in a file.

```
wc -l filename
```

Comment: i already used select count(*) from table and append counts of source data base into one file. and i alse used wc -l file name into another file.now i want to compare these counted values in these two text files and i want to generate a report in to one text file for the purpose auditing that the records loaded successfully or not.How to compare after calculating the count in to the text files.

Comment: In unix systems you can use for example the diff command. But you can use if commands in bash as well.